# Deriving a function inside an integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have to derive the following function

$\frac{d\int f(x(t))dt}{dx}$ =$f'(x(t))$

Can someone explain me why I can ignore the integral? Is there a theorem that says so?

thank you!

**EDIT (by mickep)**

Here is a scanned snippet of page 55, equation (2.16) and (2.17) in the book mentioned in the comments. I think it might be helpful for everyone to see. I don't see how that fit the question asked, though.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding the function is $\int f(x(t))dt$

Comment: That is a formula I've never seen. Are you sure it should be like this? Where did you find this formula?

Comment: This solution is in the Advanced Macroeconomics book by David Romer. However there is no satisfactory explanation of why you can do that.

Comment: I have the book in my hand. Could you give a more precise reference in that book?

Comment: pg 55 from equation 2.16 to 2.17

Comment: The problem is that there is an ambiguous notation in the equation. This is due to the use of apostrophe for the derivative which doesn't specify relatively to what variable the derivation is donne. When several different variables are involved in an equation, the use of apostrophe should be forbided. Does $f'(x(t))$ mean $\frac{df}{dx}$ or $\frac{df}{dt}$ ?

Comment: Please confirm that the equations I pasted in the question are the ones you have a problem with. If not, please delete my edit.

Comment: @JJacquelin: You are right. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the indefinite integral is that it is the anti derivative of the integrand. Precisely that if $F(x)=\int f(x) dx$ then $F'(x)=f(x)$

The fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that if $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ then $F'(x)=f(x)$

Comment: I don't think this is the problem here. The formula given by OP is very strange.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It is indeed slightly more elaborate than just a derivative. It is related to functional derivative in variational calculus. I will edit my answer as soon as possible